# Show the following integral is finite

Tags: probability, integration, lebesgue-integral

Given $f$ a probability density function that is symmetric around $0$, and assume that
$$
\int_R x^2f(x)dx < \infty,
$$
and
$$
\int_R f^2(x)dx < \infty.
$$
I want to show
$$
\int_R x^2f^2(x)dx < \infty.
$$
My way of tackling this is by separating the real line into
$$
A = \{x: f(x) > 1\}
$$
and $A^c$. Then I have
$$
\int_R x^2f^2(x)dx = \int_Ax^2f^2(x)dx + \int_{A^c}x^2f^2(x)dx < \int_Ax^2f^2(x)dx + \int_{A^c}x^2f(x)dx.
$$
So
$$
\int_R x^2f^2(x)dx < \int_Ax^2f^2(x)dx + \int_R x^2f(x)dx.
$$
I am thinking that since $f$ is a PDF, then $A$ must have finite measure. Through this I can somehow show
$$
\int_Ax^2f^2(x)dx < \infty,
$$
but I am failing in showing this inequality. Can anyone provide some hint or maybe a different way of tackling this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Let $g(x)=n$ for $n-\frac 1 {n^{5}}<x<n+\frac 1 {n^{5}}$ for $n =2,3,4...$ and $g(x)=0$ for all other positive numbers $x$. Let $g(-x)=g(x)$ for $x >0$ and $g(0)=0$.

Then $\int x^{2}g(x) dx <\infty$ and  $\int [g(x)]^{2}dx <\infty$ but $\int x^{2} [g(x)]^{2}dx =\infty$. Take $f$ to be a constant multiple of $g$ so that it becomes a probability density function.